# Line break or new paragraph inside foreach jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, foreach

I got a small problem i want to add for example i have some values in my foreach which i recive from my database how can i add a br or a p because now its just in one value

```
<c:forEach var="vac" items="${loc}">
            <div class="featurette">
                <p class="vactextl">
                        ${vac.description}
                </p>
</c:forEach>
```

I get now a text from database but i want to add a new line or break.

what i want the text is coming from a database its very long discription text i want to add breaks or paragraph in it but now i cant when i print it out there is no paragraph or anything just text is the are way to do this?

In my database is stored like this http://puu.sh/q73rp/b26d8f7014.png

But when i show it on html i get this http://puu.sh/q73uY/4026d4dc62.png

Is there a way to replace \n \r with br this would be fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Its obviously wrong way to do it like below but for now you can do it

```
<c:forEach var="vac" items="${loc}">
        <div class="featurette">
            <p class="vactextl">
                    ${vac.description}
                    <%out.println("<br>")%>
            </p>
        </d>
</c:forEach>
```

**Note**: out is jsp's implicit object

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what i want is my text is now for example Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes But is there a way to add new line inside the text because this comes from a database and just one text or do i need to do this in the database.

Comment: Erm... Why not `${vac.description}<br/>`?

Comment: @NoR3s this is a new requirement you didn't describe in you original question - instead of including it in a comment edit your question to explain you problem *properly*.

Comment: @kryger I already clear explained what i want the text is coming from a database its very long discription text i want to add breaks or paragraph in it but now i cant when i print it out there is no paragraph or anything just text

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to split your string if you want to output it with line breaks from the database. You can then try putting the split strings in an arraylist then output them in your forEach loop.

```
<c:forEach var="vac" items="${loc}">
            <div class="featurette">
                  <c:out value="${vac.description}" /><br/>
</c:forEach>
```